# How to compare values by different dates in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

My problem is related with PowerBI report

It is example table, Real table contains 10000+ results

| user | salary | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 14-10-2022 |
| 2 | 455 | 11-10-2022 |
| 3 | 333 | 13-10-2022 |
| 4 | 222 | 12-10-2022 |
| 5 | 111 | 10-10-2022 |

desired output:

| user | salary | date | salary (date-1 day) | salary (date-3 days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 14-10-2022 | 333 | 455 |
| 2 | 455 | 11-10-2022 | 111 |  |
| 3 | 333 | 13-10-2022 | 222 | 111 |
| 4 | 222 | 12-10-2022 | 455 |  |
| 5 | 111 | 10-10-2022 |  |  |

How can I achieve it in PBI ?

I tried to merge tables but the dashboard was very slow after try like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in DAX, not Power Query.

Add a date dimension (search on this if you aren’t familiar with date dimensions), then create these DAX measures.

```
Salary (date-1 day) = CALCULATE( SUM(TABLE[salary]), DATEADD(DateDim[DateKey],-1,day) )
Salary (date-3 day) = CALCULATE( SUM(TABLE[salary]), DATEADD(DateDim[DateKey],-3,day) )
```